# How to bind properly array to datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

There are a Dependency class with some properties

```
class Dependency:
{
     public string ArtifactId { get; set; }
     public string GroupId { get; set; }
     public string Version { get; set; }

     public Dependency() {}
}
```

and ProjectView class:

```
 class ProjectView:
 {
     public string Dependency[] { get; set; }
        ...
 }
```

I want to bind array of Dependencies from ProjectView class to DataGridView.

```
 class Editor
 {
     private readonly ProjectView _currentProjectView;

     ... //I skipped constructor and other methods  

     private void PopulateTabs()
     {
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource {DataSource = _currentProjectView.Dependencies, AllowNew = true};
        dataGridViewDependencies.DataSource = source;
     } 
  }
```

But when I'm binding like that, then exception occurs (AllowNew can only be set to true on an IBindingList or on a read-write list with a default public constructor.), because _currentProjectView.Dependencies is array, and it can't be able to add new items.
There is solution is convert to list, but it is not convenient, because it's just copy and lost reference to origin array. Is there solution of this problem? How to bind properly array to datagridview?
Thanks.

Comment: For me, I'd always use either a DataTable or a List object when populating Datagrid's, I wouldn't ever use an Array. why is it you want to use an Array exactly?

Comment: But I would not want to change ProjectView class

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Binding-Arrays-to-GridView-in-ASP-Net-With-Code-Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so let's say you had an array of those `Dependency` objects in memory somewhere, and you did something like this:

```
arrayOfObjs.ToList();
```

That's not going to change the reference they point to. So, to further that point, the array they came from, if it were persisted in memory, it would see the changes made. Now, will you see any additions, no? But that's why you use a mutable type like a `List` instead of an array.

So, my recommendation is that you do this:

```
class ProjectView:
{
    public string List<Dependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
}
```

And dump the array. If the original list of `Dependency` is coming from an array, well then just issue the `ToList` method on it and dump it. When you want to get an array back out of it (maybe you need to pass an array back), just do this:

```
projectViewObj.Dependencies.ToArray();
```

That will build `Dependency[]` for you.

### EDIT

So consider the following structure:

```
class ProjectView:
{
    public Dependency[] Dependencies { get; set; }

    public List<Dependency> DependencyList { get { return this.Dependencies.ToList(); } }
}
```

Then in the form:

```
private void PopulateTabs()
{
   BindingSource source = new BindingSource { DataSource = _currentProjectView.DependencyList, AllowNew = true};
   dataGridViewDependencies.DataSource = source;
}
```

And then when editing is finished:

```
_currentProjectView.Dependencies = _currentProjectView.DependencyList.ToArray();
```

Comment: I would not want to change ProjectView class, because I use PropertyGrid and Dependency property view doesn't fit.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov, one thing you could try is exposing it as an `IList<Dependency>` on the `ProjectView` class. I believe the `PropertyGrid` will respond with the same designer because it's actual value is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: It didn't work. Property grid has stopped to show Dependency property.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov, alright so I think you have two options. The first is to add a new property to `ProjectView` that is a `get` only and literally just returns `Dependencies.ToList()` - I like that one because it maintains the array you need too. Or you can build the list when you set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

Comment: how can help me a building the list during of build DataSource? All that I can, it is edit Dependencies, but if I'll add new one, then it will not saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't bind an array to `DataGridView` without using collections. So you have to use something like this:

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource {DataSource = _currentProjectView.Dependencies, AllowNew = true};

dataGridViewDependencies.DataSource = _currentProjectView.Dependencies.ToList();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx):

The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:

- The `IList` interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
- The `IListSource` interface, such as the `DataTable` and `DataSet` classes.
- The `IBindingList` interface, such as the `BindingList<T>` class.
- The `IBindingListView` interface, such as the `BindingSource` class.